# Are there attributes that affect how the CLR optimizes during a JIT compile?

Tags: .net, optimization, attributes, clr

As the question says, I am curious if any of you know about attributes that affect how the CLR will compile/optimize the bytecode. Is there an attribute that will affect code inlining decisions? Unroll loops?

Are there undocumented attributes on classes generated for anonymous types/delegates?

There's probably attributes to disable optimizations for debug purposes, but somehow I am not so interested in those.

Comment: "Are there undocumented attributes on classes generated for anonymous types/delegates?" - compile some anonymous types and delegates and check in Reflector. There are plenty of interesting attributes, but I don't recall seeing anything undocumented.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only one I've used in debugging something:

```
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
```

This prevents JIT from inlining a method. There's also a:

```
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoOptimization)]
```

Which just prevents JIT from optimizing anything, in case you found a rare bug in code generation that's actually causing the issue.

Comment: It wasn't exactly the answer I was hoping for... but thanks for the answer!